# How to save entire Swift class as String?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a swift class that looks like this

import Foundation

```
class MCPerson{
 var firstName: String
 var lastName: String
 var age: Int

init(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int){
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.age = age
 }

}
```

I want to save this entire class as string which can look like this..

```
 var str = "class MCPerson{var firstName: String
 var lastName: String
 var age: Int

init(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int){
 self.firstName = firstName
 self.lastName = lastName
 self.age = age
 }

}"
```

Can anyone please help??

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

You can't store an implementation like this. When you compile your code all swift classes are converted into **binary form**. Hence you cant get it as string. If you want the above you have your class as file. (meaning
 **As text file)**. So that you can read that file and have it as string.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually wanted to put the code lines in a single string in Swift you would need to add quotes around each line and include escaped newline characters and a concatenation character:

```
var str = "class MCPerson{var firstName: String\n" +
" var lastName: String\n" +
" var age: Int\n" +
"\n" +
"init(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int){\n" +
" self.firstName = firstName\n" +
" self.lastName = lastName\n" +
" self.age = age\n" +
" }\n" +
"\n" +
"}"
```

But it is in general useless to put code in a string and probably does not achieve the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty meaningless. Your running program does not have access to it's source code. Further, an iOS device does not have a compiler on it. So you can't get at the source code once your program is compiled, and you couldn't do anything with it even if you could.

So the answer is "You can't, and it wouldn't do you any good even if you could."